# Exo PlayerView first frame stretch to full screen

Tags: android, exoplayer

[image]

I use `PlayerView` to play mp4 video file, but the first frame always stretch to full screen. How can we avoid that? This is code I config `Player` and `PlayerView`

```
        player = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(requireContext()).build().apply {
            playWhenReady = this@VideoPlayerFragment.playWhenReady
            seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition)
            setMediaSource(mediaSource, false)
            prepare()
        }

        video_view.player = player
```

Comment: have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

i had `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in StyledPlayerView tag which caused the problem, remove it. also make sure parent view doesn't have `animateLayoutChanges` attribute
here is the full exoplayer xml

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:animation_enabled="false"
    app:auto_show="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:repeat_toggle_modes="none"
    app:resize_mode="fit"
    app:show_timeout="3000"
    app:surface_type="texture_view"
    app:use_controller="true" />
```